Short film which is shown through the eyes of a coma patient
A friend of mine recently recounted a short film he had seen (not sure how long ago), where the entire film (around 10 minutes long according to him) is shown from the perspective of a coma patient lying in a hospital bed looking directly at a wall clock.
The entire film consists of the time ticking on the clock, but all the background noises (which include the crying family and the hustle and bustle of the hospital) give context to the narrative. The big twist (which reveals that the film is shown from the eyes of a coma patient) is given at the very end.
P.S. - The film might be of Iranian origin, but my friend was not entirely sure about this.

Could this be Stimuli (2020)? It's approx. 15 minutes in length and featured at several film festivals.

Early on, we meet a man seemingly confined to a room where the reality of his surroundings appears blurred: objects come and go, and his environment lacks palpability. This portrayal effectively captures the unsteady thoughts of a comatose patient, the passage of time, and the feeling of isolation within a body that can no longer communicate with the outside world as before.
A poignant metaphor emerges as we realize the room, with its solitary peephole, symbolizes the impassable frontier between the patient’s mind and reality. Time is distorted on the other side of this border, and the patient grasps only fragments of the real world, where relatives or doctors occasionally visit.
Per review

You can see a trailer on the director's website. Ticking clocks and hospital sounds feature prominently.



